# CMake Fortran and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake, fortran

I have a project with CMake build system. Project type is Fortran

```
project(ProjectName Fortran)
```

and the Fortran compiler is recognized as well as the source code.

When trying to create a Visual Studio 9 2008 with

```
$ cmake . -G "Visual Studio 9 2008"
```

I get a Visual Studio project file for a C++ project. Which is obviously wrong. I do not have any hints on C/C++ in the project. Do I need to specify another command line option or do I need additional information in CMakeLists.txt?

**[UPDATE]**

I found in the /build directory of CMake some .vfproj files (beside a corresponding .vcproj file) which contain Fortran project files which are also readable by Visual Studio. The files where in directories with binary targets and modules. But in parent directories were none.

So, what is the trick to get one central Fortran Visual Studion project file for the whole project? I am still puzzled... Is it possible at all?

Comment: Have you seen the last 2 links in the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186110/cmake-tutorial)?

Comment: I have found it before, too. BUt, I do not see, how it could help. :-( I get a C/C++ project generated, but I do not have any hints for that in my CMakeLists.txt files. I also did not find additional parameter which might help. Also not in the links you mentioned. Do you have a more detailed hint on this topic? Maybe, I miss something here.

Comment: No - I'm afraid I don't use Fortran, so I'm not much use to you.  The [mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/mailing.html) is pretty friendly though.  You could try asking there.

Comment: Yeah, I will ask the mailing list. I thought here would be someone with the same issue... Thanks anyways!

Comment: Which suffix do your source files use? If you use some non-standard suffix, CMake might not recognize your source files as being Fortran. By default, it then generates C projects. You might also try setting the linker language property of the library or executable explicitly, see set_target_properties.

Comment: This is an interesting point... The files are ended with .f and .f90. Both suffixes are quite common for Fortran. Is CMake recognizing them? What are the default suffixes for CMake for Fortran? The set_target_properties idea is worth a try.

Comment: I tried the setting of the LINKER_LANGUAGE with set_target_properties, but this didn't help. The project is still generated as Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

You only show one line of code from your CMakeLists file:

```
project(ProjectName Fortran)
```

How do you go about adding references to your fortran source files? It should be something like this:

```
add_library(MyFLib1 MyFLib1.f)
```

Or this:

```
add_executable(MyFExe MyFExe.f)
```

If you add a library and an executable that are based solely on fortran source files, then CMake should generate a *.vfproj file for each one.

If not, it's a bug...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `project (ProjectName Fortran)` should work.

The other option is to `enable_language (Fortran)`.